# actionButton Icon Disappears When Adding Icons to Leaflet easyButton in R Shiny App

Tags: r, shiny, leaflet, icons

For some reason adding easyButtons to my R Shiny app causes the icon in the actionButton to disappear. The app is basically a leaflet map with a panel where the user can select some options to superimpose on the map some other data products. Not sure what is going on, reprex below:

```
shinyApp(

    ui = fluidPage(
    
        tabPanel('Map',

            div(class = 'outer',

                leafletOutput('Map', width = '1000px', height = '500px'),

                absolutePanel(
                    id = 'controls', 
                    class = 'panel panel-default', 
                    fixed = TRUE, 
                    draggable = FALSE, 
                    top = 70, right = 20, left = 'auto', bottom = 'auto', 
                    width = 330, height = 'auto',
                    

                    h2('Example'), 
                    br(),
                    actionButton('plot', 'Plot', icon = icon('map-marker'))
                    
                )
                
            )
            
        )

    ),
    server = function(input, output, session) {
    
        output$Map = renderLeaflet({

            leaflet() %>%
                addProviderTiles('Esri.WorldImagery') %>%
                addEasyButton(
                easyButton(id = 'edit-btn', states = list(
                  easyButtonState( 
                    stateName = 'add-toolbar',
                    icon = icon('toggle-off'),
                    title = 'Edit',
                    onClick = JS("
                      function(btn, map) {
                        Shiny.onInputChange('edit_btn', 'TRUE');
                        btn.state('remove-toolbar');
                      }"
                    )
                  ),
                  easyButtonState(
                    stateName = 'remove-toolbar',
                    icon = icon('toggle-on'),
                    title = 'Editing',
                    onClick = JS("
                      function(btn, map) {
                        Shiny.onInputChange('edit_btn', 'FALSE');
                        btn.state('add-toolbar');
                      }"
                    )
                  ))
                )
                ) 
        
        })
        
    }
    
)
```

Session info below:

```
> sessionInfo()
R version 4.0.3 (2020-10-10)
Platform: x86_64-w64-mingw32/x64 (64-bit)
Running under: Windows 10 x64 (build 17763)

Matrix products: default

locale:
[1] LC_COLLATE=English_United States.1252  LC_CTYPE=English_United States.1252   
[3] LC_MONETARY=English_United States.1252 LC_NUMERIC=C                          
[5] LC_TIME=English_United States.1252    

attached base packages:
[1] stats     graphics  grDevices utils     datasets  methods   base     

other attached packages:
 [1] stringr_1.4.0        purrr_0.3.4          magrittr_2.0.1       dplyr_1.0.2         
 [5] sf_0.9-7             raster_3.4-5         sp_1.4-4             leaflet.extras_1.0.0
 [9] leaflet_2.0.3        shinydashboard_0.7.1 shinyBS_0.61         shinyjs_2.0.0       
[13] shiny_1.5.0         

loaded via a namespace (and not attached):
 [1] tidyselect_1.1.0        lattice_0.20-41         leaflet.providers_1.9.0 colorspace_2.0-0       
 [5] vctrs_0.3.5             generics_0.1.0          htmltools_0.5.0         viridisLite_0.3.0      
 [9] base64enc_0.1-3         yaml_2.2.1              rlang_0.4.9             e1071_1.7-4            
[13] later_1.1.0.1           pillar_1.4.7            glue_1.4.2              withr_2.3.0            
[17] DBI_1.1.0               RColorBrewer_1.1-2      lifecycle_0.2.0         munsell_0.5.0          
[21] gtable_0.3.0            htmlwidgets_1.5.2       codetools_0.2-16        bs4Dash_0.5.0          
[25] fastmap_1.0.1           httpuv_1.5.4            crosstalk_1.1.0.1       class_7.3-17           
[29] Rcpp_1.0.5              KernSmooth_2.23-17      xtable_1.8-4            promises_1.1.1         
[33] scales_1.1.1            classInt_0.4-3          jsonlite_1.7.1          mime_0.9               
[37] farver_2.0.3            gridExtra_2.3           png_0.1-7               ggplot2_3.3.2          
[41] digest_0.6.27           stringi_1.5.3           grid_4.0.3              rgdal_1.5-18           
[45] tools_4.0.3             tibble_3.0.4            crayon_1.3.4            pkgconfig_2.0.3        
[49] ellipsis_0.3.1          rstudioapi_0.13         viridis_0.5.1           R6_2.5.0               
[53] units_0.6-7             compiler_4.0.3
```

Screenshot:

[image]

Comment: It seems it might be specific to the icon('map-marker'). Other icons seem to work...